# Iterating table columns & constructing JSON - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

This might be a trivial question, but I am a bit confused how to extract column data & construct an object.

The table is dynamic in nature, generated based on the data provided.

The format is like this

```
<tr>
   <td> Label </td>
   <td> 
        <input type = "radio" value="yes"/> YES 
        <input type = "radio" value="no"/>  NO  
        <textarea> 
   </td>
   <td> 
        <input type = "radio" value="yes"/> YES 
        <input type = "radio" value="no"/>  NO  
        <textarea> 
   </td>

   // This structure can repeat
   ...
   ...
</tr>

// Rows will repeat themselves
```

I have jotted up this so far

```
$(function () {
$('#submit').click(function () {
    var i = 0;
    var t = document.getElementById('table');
    $("#table tr").each(function () {
        var columns = $(this).find('td');

        /* how to extract column data here?, so that I construct
           a column object and keep looping for the other columns 


    });
});
```

My JSON needs to be like this:
[{label:data, isPresent:data, value:data}, {..}, {..}]

I am unable to get the data of both columns () in one go and then loop over the next 2 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your question, I assume you're quite new at jQuery, so I'm gonna give you a simple solution that can be used in a lot of ways.

I advise you to add classes to your HTML. This way, we can identify all the properties of the table row, independent of where the HTML-element is located in the tr-tag or what type of tag the data is placed into:

```
<tr>
   <td class="item-label"> Label </td>
   <td> 
        <input class="item-option-yes" type="radio" value="yes"/> YES 
        <input class="item-option-no" type="radio" value="no"/>  NO  
   </td>
   ... other cells with data ...
</tr>
... other rows ...
```

In your each-function, you can combine the $(this) and the find()-functions to construct your JSON-object

```
$(function () {
$('#submit').click(function () {
    var itemArray = [];

    $("#table tr").each(function (index) {
        var itemData = {
            "label": $(this).find(".item-label").text(),
            "isPresent": $(this).find(".item-option-yes")[0].checked,
            "value": $(this).find(".some-other-class").text()
        };
        itemArray.push(itemData);
    });
});
```

For more information about the find, $(this) and each-functions, please check the jQuery website

Comment: I was able to do it, but this seems much elegant solution. I have one question. The for each loop iterates over each <td> of the row, so when we do `find(".item-label")`, there is no element with that class in the <td> then how does it find the value of that element?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the columns can repeat in a row... what needs to be modified in the solution?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're saying in your comments. Can you give a better example of how your HTML code looks like with the different types of rows and columns?

Comment: I have edited the question. Basically in each row there can be more than 1 columns having the same input params (radio buttons & checkboxes). When I use the above mentioned approach it just works for the 1st column

Comment: Try giving the <td> with the radio buttons a class (for example item-option). Assuming the td's are always in the same order, you can then iterate trough the different labels with `$(this).find(".item-label").each()`

Comment: If you want to find the matching radio-button, use the `next(".item-option")`in the inner each loop.

Comment: yeah, I am trying that. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for all the help :)  finally got it working. It looks a bit messy, will refactor it tomorrow morning. :